# nodejs cannot find local folder module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a simple Typescript & NodeJS Visual Studio project, and compilation is successful but I get a node runtime error about not being able to find a local module.

This is the error given:

[image]

I don't understand why the Typescript build succeeded, but the node runtime failed to resolve the module. For the record, I have `"type": "module"` in my package.json file. For relevancy, here is my directory tree (build is the output directory for the Typescript build):

[image]

Here is the file the error is complaining about, `build\application.js`:

[image]

Lastly, here is my `package.json`.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. I feel like I'm missing something here.

EDIT: Adding source\index.js and source\test.js

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show `source/index.js` what is inside?

Comment: @AivanMonceller I've added pictures of `source/index.js` and `source/test.js` in an edit.

Comment: in `index` try `export identity;` without brackets { }`

Comment: I got the `(JS) Declaration or statement expected.` syntax error, so it looks like that syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using only the name of the folder

'. /source'

You need to point to the exact file, for example

'. /source/index'

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was under the impression that node module resolution will look for an `index.js` file if the file in the import is in fact a folder, and I know I've used that with index files before. Has something changed since?

Comment: Perhaps you migth be confusing the entry point of the transpiler/boundler with the module import & export system(?)...